# Disabling the screenshot facility in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on an enterprise Windows Phone application for a client, the issue at hand is customer information will show up on the phone. My client is worried that the information could be caught using the Windows Phone screen capture feature (Power + Volume Up button), then emailed or synced from the phone memory. Is there any way to disable the screen capture feature in Windows phone? Can this be done programmatically in C# language or is is possible through a configuration profile?

If we can disable the screenshot feature from Windows Phone, the app security will increase more, and one cannot share the data which shown on screen by taking screenshot and share it as image of screenshot via mail or any other channel.

Comment: http://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/01/20/disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app

Comment: This is the same as developers who disable keypresses and right-clicks on web pages to try to prevent copy-paste. There is always another way (in this case it involves another phone or camera taking a photo of the screen) and you will just annoy your users. My advice: don't bother.

Comment: You are right, but for security it can be a feature and Client need so anyhow I need to develop it, if you can help in Programming let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can set SetScreenCaptureEnabled as false to achieve this

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (this.CanSetScreenCaptureEnabled())
        {
            this.SetScreenCaptureEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're publishing the app only for 8.1, you'll want to verify the OS version, as this only works on GDR2 and later. [More information here.](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/01/20/disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app/)